# [proof] tag (again)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, tag-blacklist

In the past we had [a](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/132/stop-tagging-things-with-the-tag-proofs) [couple](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843/do-we-need-the-proof-tag) of discussions, and it was decided -- I thought -- that the tag [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof) shouldn't be used. Now we have more than 50 questions with this tag again. Could we please <s>get it merged with</s> make it synonym of [tag-removed]? (Or disable it in some other way.)

Comment: Tag suggestions go here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363/tag-merging-and-synonyms

Comment: @Qiaochu I'm not sure: no one will see it there, and if there are so many questions with this tag already, maybe we need some discussion.

Comment: Wow, we have zombie tags now?

Comment: @J.M.: Does that imply soon questions tagged with [tag:proof] will be titled "Braaaaaiiiinnnnn..." and will turn more tags into zombie tags??

Comment: Can we please stop re-creating [tag-removed] and properly delete tags?

Comment: @Isaac But what happens if someone uses deleted tag again? I don't want to return to this problem for 4th time.

Comment: @Grigory: Merging a tag into [tag-removed] has no effect on future use of the tag; tag synonyms affect future use, but making something a tag synonym for [tag-removed] would be ridiculous.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, I removed the [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof) tag and added it to the blacklist.

Answer (score 8):

I believe that if there is a reason to blacklist tag [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof), the same reasoning should also work for the plural - the tag [proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proofs). Since this tag [has been created recently](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2017/4/1), it is evidently not on the blacklist. Could the plural form be also blacklisted?

<sup>I assume that this probably should have been posted as a separate question. However, to me it seemed a bit redundant to create two posts about nearly identical issue.</sup>

---

EDIT: The tag is now blacklisted. If a users tries to post a question with this tag, they get the following warning:

> The 'proofs' tag is not allowed.
>
> Use [proof-writing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-writing) if you'd like advice on the presentation of your proof, or [proof-verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-writing) if you'd like feedback on its validity.
>
> Otherwise, simply tag the question according to the area of mathematics it concerns.

[image: screenshot of the warning]

Comment: I've pinged a CM to add this to the blacklist. Being a weekend and all, I don't expect this to get done before Monday.

Comment: This is now completed.

Comment: Thanks for taking care of this!

Comment: I keep trying to click the [x] on the red message.