# The "proof" tag and others

Tags: discussion, tagging

> The 'proofs' tag is not allowed. 
>  Use *proof-writing* if you'd like advice on the presentation of your proof, or *proof-verification* if you'd like feedback on its validity. 
>  Otherwise, simply tag the question according to the area of mathematics that it concerns.

Plainly it is not true that all questions about proofs are ask for advice on writing proofs or verification of proofs. We have [proof-explanation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-explanation), which is "for explanation and clarification of some steps of a particular proof" and [proof-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-theory), which is about "proof[s] as formal mathematical objects".

None of the above fits for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2620139/is-there-an-essential-difference-between-cartwrights-and-nivens-proofs-of-the).

That all questions about proofs fit within what is quoted above, so that the word "Otherwise" is appropriate, is exaggerated.

I have created the [understanding-proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/understanding-proofs) tag. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Any reason why you think you need to add a tag concerning proofs, instead of "simply tag the question according to the area of mathematics that it concerns" as suggested?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think this is a good tag. Classifying a question as "trying to understand a proof" isn't necessary - it's implied by the question itself. It doesn't help to organize, because there aren't enough commonalities between questions that are about understanding particular proofs.

Comment: The [current revision](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/27789/2) of the question starts with a quote without any explanation where this quote is taken from. So I'll add that this is the warning which a user gets if they try to make a post with the blacklisted (proofs) tag. I have added also a screenshot [in this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2110/proof-tag-again/26116#26116).

Comment: I have seen many post beg8nning with *confirmation of proof: …* including my own ones, so perhaps we could invent a tag **(confirmation-of-proof)** or **(proof-confirmation)** as well?

Comment: @user477343 Isn't the existing tag ([tag:proof-verification]) basically what you're asking for in your comment?